# CSS Floating, overflow and absolute position

Tags: html, css

I have a left floated sidebar with a dropdown menu that is absolutely positioned and extends out over the main content.

The main content has background colors that must not go under the sidebar.

Some of the content also contains a drop down that is absolutely positioned and whose content extends beyond its parents boundaries.

The content is in blocks. The blocks should completely float to the left of the side bar, or once the side bar is cleared then they should take up the whole horizontal width.

Normally all of these rules could be satisfied except for the drop down in the content. This would be done by applying 'overflow: hidden' to the content elements as this would contain the background. However in this case the dropdown in the content area is causing problems because it expands beyond its parent vertical boundary and causes it to be hidden. (I've used 'overflow: scroll' rather than 'hidden' on the demo to highlight the problem).

Edit to add: I've tried using only 'overflow-x: hidden' and overflow-y: visible' but for some reason it doesn't work.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPrjS/3/)

Alternatively here is the html and css:

```
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="sidebar_dropdown">
        sidebar_dropdown
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>  
  <div id="content_2">
    something more content with an absolutly positioned drop down.
    <div id="dropdown">
      dropdown content
      <br/>
      dropdown content
      <br/>
      dropdown content
      <br/>
      dropdown content
      <br/>      
      dropdown content
      <br/>   
      dropdown content
      <br/>           
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    some content hidden by dropdown.
  </div>
    <div class="content">
    some content
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div> 
  <div class="content">
    some content
  </div>     
</body>
```

css:

```
#sidebar {
  float: right;
  margin:0 1em;
  background-color: #8888ff;
  height: 10em;
  width: 5em;
  position:relative;
}

#sidebar_dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;  
  top: 1em;
  background-color: #888888;    
}

.content {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #ff8888;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content_2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background-color: #88ff88;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;    
}

#dropdown {
  background-color: #88ffff;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: could you just clarify what you are trying to achieve? Does the drop dow have to be positioned absolute?

Comment: I am trying to make it so that the dropdown in the content is not cut off due to the overflow: hidden. If you check the fiddle, you will see that half of it is not shown.

Comment: do you need <div id="dropdown"> to be positioned absolute?

Comment: @ericLemos There may be a way of floating it and using a margin. But it has to be relative to a textbox that varies in position (It is a suggestions dropdown)

Comment: @EricLemos No, that will not work. There is content below the dropdown that is shifted around if it is not absolutely positioned.

Comment: @EricLemos But I could try putting the dropdown outside of the content plane and then absolutely positioning it with js. I am using js to populate it anyway so its not a major deal. that should work. I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by inserting the content dropdown with js (I was already doing this so it is not a problem, as it is populated via ajax).

Instead of inserting it relative to the textbox it belonged to, I inserted at the top of the body and then calculated it's position from the textbox. Thus it is higher up the render tree than the content plane that has the 'overflow hidden' applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use overflow:hidden on absolute elements - **in your case** -, you will have to wrap them with another absolute element reflecting it's parent (width and height must be the same).

HTML

```
<div id="hideOverflow">
    <div id="sidebar_dropdown">
        sidebar_dropdown
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hideOverflow { width: 5em; height: 10em; position:absolute; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: My problem is with the dropdown in the content plane, not the one on the sidebar (I included it because some solutions I've tried messed up the sidebar dropdown). The problem is that the dropdown is cut offf due to the overflow hidden of its parent.